# react-native link - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-linking

Following the Documentation of [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android#1)-Link-RNFirebase)
Having this error when try to link the installed package.

`react-native link react-native-firebase`

> Scanning folders for symlinks in /PROJ-DIR/node_modules (45ms)
>   rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

There was already an issue raised against this [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12188)
but solutions are based on a problem with Xcode.
I'm not working for ios yet.
A [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12188#issuecomment-338972602) regarding android is not working too.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your android and ios folders and use following commands:

1.**react-native eject** to recreate android and ios folders.

2.**react-native upgrade** Be careful while running this command because it will replace your configuration files.

3.Finally **react-native link**

Many a times i too get this error and I follow these steps to overcome.
Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12188)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't followed SO since then, and I solved by following [this doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure is there any unwanted changes are done in ios's project file. if yes then revert back as it is.

I faced this error after merging two branch and i have accepted both changes and got error and fixed it by proper merging